# Rendering with uniform block to fbo causes some objects to flicker

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

I wanted to implement shadow mapping for my game engine, and I therefore had to render the depth view to a fbo. I've rendered the depth texture and scaled the values so that the texture doesn't look completely white, and the result looks correct. However, some of the objects in the scene disappear every other frame or so, something that has never ever occurred before. I've simplified the code and it now looks something like the following;

1. Update uniform buffer object
2. Bind fbo
3. Render to fbo
4. Bind default fbo
5. Render scene as usual

The flickering of the objects goes away if:

The uniform block inside the shader used when rendering to the fbo is removed, even though it was never accessed.

We never bind the fbo (we remove step (2) from the simplified pseudo code)

We swap the order of some render calls inside step (5)

We update the uniform buffer object after we render to the fbo, i.e. move step (1) to somewhere after step (3). We only update some of the elements of the ubo inside step (1), but regardless of what elements are updated the problem goes away when moving the step. Notice that removing the step completely doesn't remove the error.

We never render to the fbo (we remove step (3))

Notice that the uniform block is accessed inside the shaders of the draw calls inside step (5). I've created an identical uniform buffer object and accessed that one instead inside the shader used when rendering to the fbo, and the flickering goes away, so it looks like the issue is that I'm accessing the same ubo when rendering to the fbo as when I'm rendering to the default framebuffer. However, as far as I know this shouldn't be an issue. I'm using all the variables inside the uniform block so it seems to have been initialized correctly.

EDIT:
I've simplified the code as much as I could. After simplifying one of the shaders, the object rendered disappears completely instead of flickers, but that does not make the issue any better. The invisible render call is "render call B". All of the observations above still hold true. Some new observations have been made and there are comments about these inside the below code.

The complete source code:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>

static void AttachShader(unsigned int program, GLenum type, const std::string& source)
{
    unsigned int shader = glCreateShader(type);
    const char* cString = source.c_str();
    glShaderSource(shader, 1, &cString, NULL);
    glCompileShader(shader);

    int status;
    glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status);
    assert(status);
    glAttachShader(program, shader);
}

int main(void)
{
    GLFWwindow* window;

    /* Initialize the library */
    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;

    /* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    /* Make the window's context current */
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    GLenum err = glewInit();
    assert(GLEW_OK == err);

    /* Loop until the user closes the window */
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        /* Render here */
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        static bool first = true;
        static unsigned int vao;
        static unsigned int framebuffer;
        static unsigned int shadowMapTexture;
        static unsigned int uniformBuffer;
        static unsigned int programA;
        static unsigned int programB;
        static float identity[16] =
        { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
          0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
          0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
          0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };

        if (first)
        {
            first = false;

            //Creating program A
            {
                programA = glCreateProgram();
                AttachShader(programA, GL_VERTEX_SHADER,
                    "#version 450 core\n\
            \n\
            //If the data block gets commented the issue goes away\n\
            layout(std140, binding = 0) uniform DataBlock\n\
            {\n\
                mat4 identity;\n\
            }dataBlock;\n\
            \n\
            \n\
            void main()\n\
            {\n\
                vec3 positions[3] = { vec3(-0.5, -0.25, -0.2), vec3(0.0, -0.25, -0.2), vec3(-0.25, 0.25, -0.2) };\n\
                gl_Position = vec4(positions[gl_VertexID], 1.0);\n\
            }");
                AttachShader(programA, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER,
                    "#version 450 core\n\
            out vec4 colour;\n\
            \n\
            void main()\n\
            {\n\
                colour = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);\n\
            }");
                glLinkProgram(programA);

                int status;
                glGetProgramiv(programA, GL_LINK_STATUS, &status);
                assert(status);
            }

            //Creating program B
            {
                programB = glCreateProgram();
                AttachShader(programB, GL_VERTEX_SHADER,
                    "#version 450 core\n\
\n\
            layout(location = 0) in int index;\n\
            layout(location = 1) uniform mat4[2] matrices;\n\
\n\
            layout(std140, binding = 0) uniform DataBlock\n\
            {\n\
                mat4 identity;\n\
            }dataBlock;\n\
\n\
            void main()\n\
            {\n\
\n\
                vec3 positions[3] = { vec3(-0.25, -0.25, -0.2), vec3(0.25, -0.25, -0.2), vec3(0.0, 0.25, -0.2) };\n\
\n\
                vec4 pos = vec4(positions[gl_VertexID], 1.0);\n\
\n\
                //If \"index\" is substituted by \"0\" the problem goes away\n\
                vec4 secondPos = matrices[index] * pos;\n\
\n\
                //If \"secondPos\" is substituted by \"pos\" the problem remains\n\
                //If we remove \"dataBlock.identity *\" the problem goes away\n\
                gl_Position = dataBlock.identity*secondPos;\n\
            }");
                AttachShader(programB, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER,
                    "#version 450 core\n\
\n\
            out vec4 colour;\n\
\n\
            void main()\n\
            {\n\
                colour = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);\n\
            }");
                glLinkProgram(programB);

                int status;
                glGetProgramiv(programB, GL_LINK_STATUS, &status);
                assert(status);
            }

            //Creating the vao used inside shader "B"
            {
                glCreateVertexArrays(1, &vao);

                unsigned int vertexBuffer;
                glCreateBuffers(1, &vertexBuffer);
                int vertexData[3] = { 0,0,0 };
                glNamedBufferData(vertexBuffer, sizeof(int) * 3, vertexData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
                glVertexArrayVertexBuffer(vao, 0, vertexBuffer, 0, sizeof(int));
                glVertexArrayAttribBinding(vao, 0, 0);
                glVertexArrayAttribIFormat(vao, 0, 1, GL_INT, 0);
                glEnableVertexArrayAttrib(vao, 0);
            }

            //Creating the framebuffer
            {
                glCreateFramebuffers(1, &framebuffer);
                glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);

                glGenTextures(1, &shadowMapTexture);
                glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, shadowMapTexture);
                glTexStorage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32F, 512, 512);
                glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
                glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

                glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, shadowMapTexture, 0);

                unsigned int drawBuffers[] = { GL_NONE };
                glDrawBuffers(1, drawBuffers);

                assert(glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) == GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE);
            }

            //Creating the uniform buffer object
            {
                glCreateBuffers(1, &uniformBuffer);
                glNamedBufferStorage(uniformBuffer, sizeof(float)*16, NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_STORAGE_BIT);
                glBindBufferBase(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0, uniformBuffer);
                glNamedBufferSubData(uniformBuffer, 0, sizeof(float) * 16, identity);
            }

            //Creating and binding a vao for compatability with the core profile
            static unsigned int emptyVao;
            glCreateVertexArrays(1, &emptyVao);
            glBindVertexArray(emptyVao);
        }

        //Step 2, binding the fbo
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        //End of step 2

        //Step 3, rendering to fbo
        {
            glUseProgram(programA);
            glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
        }

        //If we update the uniform buffer here the issue disappears, i.e. if the following line gets uncommented 
        {
            //glNamedBufferSubData(uniformBuffer, 0, sizeof(float) * 16, identity);
        }

        //Step 4, binding the default fbo
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        //If the following line gets uncommented the issue goes away
        //glUseProgram(programB);


        //Render call A
        glUseProgram(programA);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

        //Render call B
        glBindVertexArray(vao);
        glUseProgram(programB);
        float* matrices = new float[sizeof(float) * 16 * 2];

        for (size_t i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
        {
            memcpy((char*)matrices + i * sizeof(float) * 16, (char*)identity, sizeof(float) * 16);
        }
        glUniformMatrix4fv(1, 2, GL_FALSE, matrices);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

        assert(glGetError() == 0);

        /* Swap front and back buffers */
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        /* Poll for and process events */
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Program A:

Vertex shader:

```
#version 450 core

//If the data block gets commented the issue goes away
layout(std140, binding = 0) uniform DataBlock
{
    mat4 identity;
}dataBlock;


void main()
{
    vec3 positions[3] = { vec3(-0.5, -0.25, -0.2), vec3(0.0, -0.25, -0.2), vec3(-0.25, 0.25, -0.2) };
    gl_Position = vec4(positions[gl_VertexID], 1.0);
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
#version 450 core
out vec4 colour;

void main()
{
    colour = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);

}
```

Program B:

Vertex shader:

```
#version 450 core


layout(location = 0) in int index;
layout(location = 1) uniform mat4[2] matrices;



layout(std140, binding = 0) uniform DataBlock
{
    mat4 identity;
}dataBlock;


void main()
{

    vec3 positions[3] = { vec3(-0.25, -0.25, -0.2), vec3(0.25, -0.25, -0.2), vec3(0.0, 0.25, -0.2) };
    
    vec4 pos = vec4(positions[gl_VertexID], 1.0);
    
    //If "index" is substituted by "0" the problem goes away
    vec4 secondPos = matrices[index] * pos;
    
    //If "secondPos" is substituted by "pos" the problem remains
    //If we remove "dataBlock.identity *" the problem goes away
    gl_Position = dataBlock.identity*secondPos;
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
#version 450 core

out vec4 colour;

void main()
{
    colour = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
}
```

glGetError() only returns zeros. I'm completely lost, and don't know how to proceed. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide the _actual_ source code which produces the issue. With so little information given, it is hard to tell what might be going on. On first impression, I'd assume some state leaking between your RTT pass and the main render pass, but it is impossible to guess any details out of thin air.

Comment: @derhass Thank you for your help! I've added some additional source code. If you want even more it would be helpful if you could specify which code snippets you need. What is a RTT pass?

Comment: Well, the code snippets we would need would be something which makes this a [minimal _reproducible_ example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). "RTT" means "render to texture".

Comment: @derhass Thank you once again for your help! It took quite some time, but I've added almost all the code

Comment: All the shadermanager code is still missing. Furthermore, you're not clearing the depth buffer before rendering to the default framebuffer, and your "B"-Shader has two different uniforms assigned to location 0.

Comment: @derhass Thank you for pointing out these mistakes! I've corrected them (the issue remains) and I'm working on the displayment of the shader management stuff

Comment: sorry, I was confused about those locations, you has these as input and unfiorm, so using location 0 for both is fine.

Comment: @derhass No problem. Now I've included all the source code (sorry for taking so long and for not being able to include from the start)

Comment: Well, I only see one issue with the code as it is posted now: it does not work in core profiles, because you use VAO 0 for drawing the first half of the first iteration. But since you don't request a core profile, it should work. And it actually _does_ work for me, on nvidia linux and windows. I can procude an abort on that final `glGetError` assertion by forcing a core profile, but that error goes away if I bind the VAO right after creating it.

Comment: @derhass Thank you for taking a look at the code! I've now added a vao that I create for the sole purpose of binding it, however the issue still remains. So you can see two triangles being rendered on the screen? Isn't this really weird? Do you think it's some kind of driver issue?

Comment: Yess, I see both triangles, Which driver are you using. This might be a bug, or I may have overlooked something and it only works by chance on nvidia drivers.

Comment: @derhass I'm using Intel(R) HD Graphics 610, version; 26.20.100.7757

Comment: yeah, this really might be a driver bug.

Comment: @derhass What would you do in my situation? How high do you think the percentage is for a random user to experience this bug?

Comment: I don't know. With the Intel GL drivers on windows, all bets are off.